# Is it bad practice to include javascript files in Joomla articles?

Tags: javascript, joomla, include

I was going to wait until the [StackExchange for Joomla](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla) was approved before asking this question, but I'd really like to know the answer now!

According to http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript there are 3 methods for incorporating javascript into Joomla using-

> JDocument::addScriptDeclaration, JDocument::addScript and script.

I believe there is a fourth way which is perhaps easier than the methods listed and that is to include the javascript into the article directly. For example, in a Joomla article I could use the following line `<script src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>`

Since this method isn't listed in the docs, I'm thinking it must be bad practice.

**QUESTIONs**

- Is it bad practice to include javascript files directly into Joomla
  via an article? If so, why?
- What reasons (if any) are there for me to choose the first 3 methods
  as opposed to the 4th? (I'm particularly interested to know if the 4th
  method would affect cache or cause problems when using cdns.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including JS in an article is a bad idea because of loading order and dependencies.
Only do that if you need the script only on that single article page and if you've tested its behavior (and if you are no coder).

Best way to do it is via:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'path_to_script/script.js', false, true);
```

If you want to embed it right and not fiddle with PHP you could use something like this:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/scripts/20245

Comment: Good answer. Personally I would recommend this extensions for adding JS to articles. It also supports PHP if need be: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051

Answer (score 1):

If you need the script only on that one page, then it's better to add it in the article itself.

You can't use JDocument::addScriptDeclaration, JDocument::addScript because these are PHP functions. Unless your editor allows you to add PHP, then you can't use them.

The 4th option is the best.

Answer (score 1):

The true answer lies in what you are trying to do with your script.  There are many uses for Java script in articles, such as syndicated features or affiliate marketing.

TinyMCE limits some of the things you can use your articles for so I use JCE Content Editor for more power and options.  There are free versions as well as pro versions available.

Check it out here: http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/